# Joining two curves in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, splines

I'm trying to get rid of some gaps in my mesh.

In object mode it looks like this
[image]

So it is one object. When I switch to edit mode it turns out that splines are subdivided. [image][image]

How do I join them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

- Find and select the end control points
- Hit <kbd>F</kbd> to join them with a new segment
- Select the point which goes least in the direction you want, and <kbd>X</kbd> dissolve it.